# SplitView Pane open from right like W10 Mail App

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

How do I create a SplitView Panel which opens from right side of the app. This is implemented in Windows 10 Mail Applications when you press on the settings icon. I've googled for this but there is nothing that can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The SplitView has a property [PanePlacement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.splitview.paneplacement) with possible values Left and Right.

```
<SplitView IsPaneOpen="True" PanePlacement="Right">
</SplitView>
```